# Django httpresponse doesn't work after submit form

Tags: python, django, forms, httpresponse

I want to submit the form and return to topics page, but it doesn't work. Here is the page before submitting.
[page before submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g9OM.png)

I enter something and click the button, it doesn't return to the page I want.The error shows as follow:
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m16MQ.png)

It seems like the views.py can't find the right URL, how can I fix it?

**view.py**:

```
def new_topic(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('leraning_log:topics'))

    context = {'form':form}     
    return render(request,'learning_logs/new_topic.html',context)
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^topics/$',views.topics,name='topics'),

    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$',views.topic,name='topic'),

    url(r'^new_topic/$',views.new_topic,name='new_topic'),
]
```

**new_topic.html**:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Add a new topic:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %} method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">add topic</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: can you add your template?

Comment: Thanks for your remind,I added it.

Comment: Look at the code coloring.. The `action=""` is not closed properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your form, just delete the action:

```
 <form method='post'>#instead of
 <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method='post'>
```

if you omit the action automatically return to the same page, also, a better practice in your view would be:

```
def new_topic(request):
    if request.method = "POST":
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('leraning_log:topics'))

    else:
        form = TopicForm()

    context = {'form':form}     
    return render(request,'learning_logs/new_topic.html',context)
```